CR3-535M Help, Mitsubishi 6-axis RV-12SL Robot arm
I'm a student working on the CR3-535M controller, which is used to control the RV-12SL 6-axis robot arm from Mitsubishi. I'm encountering the error code H109n* (H1091,H1092,H1093,H1094,H1095,H1096). The troubleshoot detail explanation image is below:
I've tried changing the rotary switch positions to 0 1 5 2 3 4 for J1,J2,J6,J3,J4,J5 respectively but that still didn't work.
So i come here to ask for your help, is there any way to solve it ?
I'll provide any information required.
Thanks.


what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Hi want to solve the H109n* error, is there any way ?

Is there anyway to solve the error ?

As the manual says, try restarting the driver, if it doesn't go back to normal you should contact the driver supplier's technical support.
